# AttributeError: module 'networkx.algorithms.community' has no attribute 'best_partition'

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, networkx, graph-theory

well i am trying to use **community detection algorithms** by **networkx** on famous facebook snap data set.
here are my codes :

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx.algorithms import community
from networkx.algorithms.community.centrality import girvan_newman

G_fb = nx.read_edgelist("./facebook_combined.txt",create_using = nx.Graph(), nodetype=int)

parts = community.best_partition(G_fb)
values = [parts.get(node) for node in G_fb.nodes()]
```

but when i'm run the cell i face with the title error which is :

```
AttributeError: module 'networkx.algorithms.community' has no attribute 'best_partition'
```

any advice ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you're confusing the [community module](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/community.html) in networkx proper with the community detection in the [python-louvain](https://python-louvain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module which *uses* networkx.

If you install python-louvain, the example in its docs works for me, and generates images like

[image: sample graph partition]

Note that you'll be importing `community`, not `networkx.algorithms.community`.  That is,

```
import community

[.. code ..]

partition = community.best_partition(G_fb)
```

Comment: when i tried import community i faced with this error : No module named 'community'

Comment: Did you actually install the `python-louvain` module?

Comment: save my day. Thanks

Comment: I'm using the exact same code as yours but still it gives the same error. Could you help?

Answer (score 12):

I faced this in CS224W

`AttributeError: module 'community' has no attribute 'best_partition'`
[image]

Pls change this file karate.py

replace import to
`import community.community_louvain as community_louvain`

then it works for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. In my case, it was solved importing the module in a different manner:

```
import community.community_louvain
```

[Source](https://www.programmersought.com/article/35095865636/)

Comment: So thanks! 
 | 
import community.community_louvain as louvain 
 | 
partitions = louvain.best_partition(G)

Answer (score 2):

I naively thought that `pip install community` was the package I was looking for but rather I needed `pip install python-louvain` which is then imported as `import community`.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this in CS224W
but changing the karate.py or other solutions didn't work.

For me (in colab) using the new PyG installation code worked.
this code, will install the last version:

```
!pip install -q torch-scatter -f https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-1.9.0+cu102.html
!pip install -q torch-sparse -f https://pytorch-geometric.com/whl/torch-1.9.0+cu102.html
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_geometric.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
In my case, it was because on the other machine the library networkx was obsolete.

With the following command, the issues was solved.

```
pip3 install --upgrade networkx
```

Answer (score 0):

This has helped me to run the code without errors:

```
pip uninstall community
import community.community_louvain as cl
partition = cl.best_partition(G_fb)
```