# AttributeError: module 'community' has no attribute 'best_partition'

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I try to run this code:

```
from cdlib import algorithms
import networkx as nx
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
coms = algorithms.louvain(G, resolution=1., randomize=False)
```

but the error remains the same.
I have tried all options given by
[AttributeError: module 'networkx.algorithms.community' has no attribute 'best_partition'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53017174/attributeerror-module-networkx-algorithms-community-has-no-attribute-best-pa)

but it doesn't work.

Also, I'm working in Google Colab and I have installed cdlib.

Answer (score 3):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087066/how-to-use-the-communities-module-python-louvain-in-networkx-2-2/53101996), it looks like there is a `community` python package that conflicts with the `python-louvain` package. Both packages happen to be pre-installed in google colab kernels. To avoid this conflict, I just uninstalled `networkx`, `python-louvain` and `community` and then reinstalled `networkx` and `python-louvain`. Finally I installed cdlib.
After that I ran your code and everything worked well. So overall the code is:

```py
!pip uninstall networkx
!pip uninstall python-louvain
!pip uninstall community
!pip install python-louvain
!pip install networkx

!pip install cdlib

from cdlib import algorithms
import networkx as nx
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
coms = algorithms.louvain(G, resolution=1., randomize=False)
print(coms)
```

And the ouput gives:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If still useful, this worked out for me :

```
pip uninstall community
pip install python-louvain
```

I could import `community` afterwards and use `best_partition`.